# Getting exception when i am creating clone of database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, clone

I want to create a clone of a database using C#, but I am getting an exception

> DBCC CLONEDATABASE cannot be executed through MARS connection.

My code:

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
sqlConnection.Open();

SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(" DBCC CLONEDATABASE (SinglePoint, SinglePoint_1) ALTER DATABASE[SinglePoint_1] SET READ_WRITE ", sqlConnection);
sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
sqlConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Can you disable multiple active result sets via your connection string and try again?

Answer (score -1):

Your connection string contains `MultipleActiveResultSets=True`, which enables the [MARS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets) feature in SQL Server. The statement you're trying to execute doesn't support this. You need to remove this from the connection string, or change the value to `False`.

Also, you are unnecessarily using a `SqlDataAdapter` for a non-query statement. Try this:

```
string sql = "DBCC CLONEDATABASE (SinglePoint, SinglePoint_1) " 
    + "ALTER DATABASE[SinglePoint_1] SET READ_WRITE";

using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
    sqlConnection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection)) {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```